# WooCommerce Rest API

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, woocommerce

The below code looks for categories in the products directory. How can I change this code to first look in products/categories and if null, look in shop/categories.

I need this to work in products/categories as well as shop/categories.

The code below works great on a WooCommerce website. However when the Dokan Plugin is installed, Dokan redirects product/categories to shop/categories.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
echo json_encode($response);

} elseif ($tag == 'viewCategoryList') {

    try {

       echo json_encode($woocommerce->get('products/categories'));

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        $response["error"] = 1;

        $response["success"] = 0;

        $response["message"] = "Invalid Product Id";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

Comment: Is there something related to dokkan rewrites in the plugin settings that you need to set ? Did you try to change the woocommerce and/or WordPress permalinks according to this fact ?

Comment: This website test displays the categories correctly using above command.
http://charterbareboats.com/samana/forms/categories.html

This website has Dokan installed and I receive an error:
http://vimarketplace.com/forms/categories.html)

You can see that on this https://vimarketplace.com/product/happy-birthday-rugged/ redirects to https://vimarketplace.com/shop/happy-birthday-rugged/

I was hoping I could add to the above code a line that looks in the shop directory if it finds the product directory empty.

Comment: I think, you'll get a success response with an empty response, you can do something like : if(empty($response['product_categories'])){echo json_encode($woocommerce->get('shop/categories');}

Comment: Keep getting 500 error. I am inserting your code incorrectly. I do not know how. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working. This is what worked!

```
} elseif ($tag == 'viewCategoryList') {

        try {
            if (!empty($response['product_categories']))
            {
                echo json_encode($woocommerce->get('shop/categories'));       
            }           
        }

        catch (Exception $e) {

            $response["error"] = 1;

            $response["success"] = 0;

            $response["message"] = "Invalid Product Id";

            echo json_encode($response);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

With the links you provide in comments, I found one mistake about the protocol of the url if the form action, as your domain is https, http must be https

```
<form action="https://vimarketplace.com/?getrequest" method="post">
```

You need to set up your script to enable ssl_verify (but if you didn't touch the value is true).

When you active Dokkan, in the wizard, leave the first field empty (you maybe setted up to shop, default is store). Maybe...

Comment: I fixed the form. The script is set up to verify the SSL.

Comment: Benoti, I appreciate all your help. The API has to work for wooCommerce websites that have the Dokan Plugin installed as well as on websites that do NOT have the Dokan plugin installed. I tried your code with if(empty as well as if(!empty but I'm not inserting it correctly or in the wrong place.